# Simple 3-D carousel in vertical direction not working properly?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I was making a carousel in the vertical direction, but on rotating `180deg` of the X-axis, the backside of the carousel seems like its orientation is not proper in the 3D space.
I would prefer that the solution provided contains not just the code, but also reasoning why this is happening.

```css
#container1 {
    position: relative;
 left: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 600px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-origin: 0 300px 0;
 perspective-origin: 100px 300px 0;
 perspective: 800px;
 animation-name: rotate;
 animation-duration: 5s;
}
@keyframes rotate {
 from {transform: rotateX(0deg);}
 to {transform: rotateX(180deg);}
}
#container1 div {
 position: absolute;
 top: 225px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
}
#div1 {
 transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(130px);
    background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
 transform: rotateX(60deg) translateZ(130px);
 background-color: blue;
}
#div3 {
 transform: rotateX(120deg) translateZ(130px);
 background-color: green;
}
#div4 {
 transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(130px);
 background-color: brown;
}
#div5 {
 transform: rotateX(240deg) translateZ(130px);
 background-color: orange;
}
#div6 {
 transform: rotateX(300deg) translateZ(130px);
 background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="container1">
      <div id="div1"></div>
      <div id="div2"></div>
      <div id="div3"></div>
      <div id="div4"></div>
      <div id="div5"></div>
      <div id="div6"></div>
  </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you put `perspective` in the `#container`. You should put the `perspective` in the "stage". Here you can the implementation: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lft9ttz9/)